# Load and Reuse Django Template Filters

Tags: python, django, templatetags

Is it possible to load a django template tag/filter to use as a function in one of my template tags?

I'm trying to load up some of the django.contrib.humanize filters so I can apply them to the results of some of my custom template tags.  I can't seem to import them at all, and I don't want to have to rewrite any of that code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Template tags are just Python functions; you can import their module and call them with impunity, the only requirement being that you pass them appropriate arguments. The `django.contrib.humanize.templatetags.humanize` module has separate functions to do the work, so it's even easier in that specific case.

Comment: Hmm. That's what I was trying, I guess I just had the wrong import path every time I tried it. It works with 

'from django.contrib.humanize.templatetags import humanize'.  So, thanks.